# django rest : @api_view and @classmethod error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I desperately need @classmethod

i am use this code:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
class MyClass():
    @classmethod
    @api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
    def CRUD(cls, request, id=0):
         #.....
         return Response({})
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^user/(?:(?P<id>[1-9]+)/)?$', UserView.CRUD)
]
```

get error:
`The 'request' argument must be an instance of 'django.http.HttpRequest', not 'builtins.type'.`

please help ; Thankful

Comment: You get that error when/where exactly? Post the complete traceback please.

Comment: `@api_view` is not suitable for class based views

Comment: @deceze for all request , i have this error

Comment: @404pio What should I do? 

Answer (score 1):

Like @404pio said. Either you use a class based view or function based view. You cannot mix them.

#### class-based-view

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class MyClass(APIView):
   def get(self, request, id):
      # do stuff
      return Response(...)
   def post(self, request, id):
      # do stuff
      return Response(...)
   .
   .
   .
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^user/(?:(?P<id>[1-9]+)/)?$', MyClass.as_view())
]
```

or

#### function-based-view

```py
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'...])
def my_fbv(request, id):
   if request.method == 'GET':
       # do stuff

    elif request.method == 'POST':
       # do stuff
    .
    .
    .
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^user/(?:(?P<id>[1-9]+)/)?$', my_module.my_fbv)
]
```